# unique string for directory

Tags: filesystems, erlang

I want to create unique directory for controlling directory's disk quota. The unique directory name is created as follows:

```
unique_string()->
    base64:encode_to_string(term_to_binary(make_ref())).
```

But when debuging, the problem appears:

```
 exception exit: {{badmatch,
                         {error,
                             " g3IAA2QAFGVtYWNzQHl1cy1pTWFjLmxvY2FsAwAB/ncAAAA8AAAAAA==: No such file or directory.\r\n"}},
```

The unique_string contains "/", it caused problems.

I am afraid if just deleting "/", the feature of unique will lost. How to solve problem?
In addition, is there any other characters can't be used in directory?

Comment: The allowed characters in file names vary per OS. Are you sure you don't want a [UUID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657204/erlang-uuid-generator) instead?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. UUID can satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `base64:encode_to_string` with a `hexify` function as follows.

```
hexify(Binary) ->
  lists:flatten([io_lib:format("~2.16.0b", [B]) || <<B>> <= Binary]).
```

You can also tweak this function to allow different set of characters used.

btw, I recommend to do some hashing on the ref to make the names of same length.

```
hexify(crypto:md5(term_to_binary(make_ref())))
```

Answer (score 1):

One erlang VM guarantee to give different values to each time request. Even on a Windows machine which usually give the time at 1 ms accuracy, multiple accesses give results at 1µs:

```
2> R = {now(),now(),now(),now()}.
{{1357,408695,109000},
 {1357,408695,109001},
 {1357,408695,109002},
 {1357,408695,109003}}
```

So if you think that the frequency of call is really less than 1 000 000 calls per sec (it is important to avoid significant perturbation on erlang time) the method works efficiently.

Comment: There's a danger to using this approach: using erlang:now() repeatedly and rapidly can cause clock skew. http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#now-0

Comment: You are right, it is why it can be used only if the average call frequency is limited.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a unique value, and you don't need more than 1 per millisecond, why not just use the current system time to the millisecond?  It is much faster than the functions you mention above, and suitably unique.

If there is a chance of getting more than one in a millisecond, you might store the last unique value in a static variable, and make sure the new one is greater than it, else use the last value plus one.

Comment: Because many process are running at same time, it is possible to conflict.

Comment: One erlang VM guarantee to give different values to each time request. Even on a Windows machine which usually give the time at 1 ms accuracy, multiple accesses give results at 1µs:

Answer (score 0):

Using ref() as a string, if you restart the VM, you could get the same dir name. Does it matters? 
As other users say, If the frequency of call is less than 1 call per microsecond you can use now().

Two sugestions

```
random_md5_name() -> 
    Str =  lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [now()])),
    lists:flatten([io_lib:format("~2.16.0b", [B]) || <<B>> <=  erlang:md5(Str)].

random_numeric_name() ->
    lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p~p~p", tuple_to_list(now()))).
```

Answer (score 0):

Riak uses sha hash from ref and timestamp for generating unique keys.

```
crypto:sha(term_to_binary({make_ref(), os:timestamp()}))
```

https://github.com/basho/riak_core/blob/1.2.1p1/src/riak_core_util.erl#L135